# How can I check the charge of an Apple iPod Shuffle?

Tags: linux, software-rec, ipod

I am using Ubuntu and would like to know the answer to this question:

- How does one determine whether his/her Apple iPod Shuffle's charge is full in Linux?

In Windows it's easy since iTunes shows the charge. But in Linux neither Rhytmbox nor gtkpod shows the battery charge. Any help regarding this.

Comment: Why can't you just look at your iPod? I'm not trying to be rude, but I also use Rhythmbox for my iPod (touch), and it's easy to check the iPod to see how charged it is.

Comment: @Cam: Cam i have an iPOD shuffle. Which has no display.

Comment: It's iPod and Apple. Not IPOD and APPLE.

Answer (score 1):

Just check it on the device itself: [iPod shuffle: Checking the battery charge](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1510)

If you are lucky enough to have a newer model, you can get fairly fine-grained information:

```
Charging Indicators when listening to iPod shuffle

Status Light    Charge Level    Audible Notification
 Green           76% - 100%     “Battery Full”
                 51% - 75%      “Battery 75%”
                 26% - 50%      “Battery 50%”
 Orange          11% - 25%      “Battery 25%”
 Red             1%-10%         “Battery Low”
 Blinking Red    less than 1%   Tri-Tone
 None            0%              None
```